# MVC and Jquery search with Data in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, search

I am looking for advice with a scenario I have.

I have a data being displayed on the page which is shown as such...

You have departments which have lists of Sections. Each section has lists of users.

like so:

```
@foreach (var d in Model.DepartmentList)
{
    <p id="@d.DeptId" class="ListDeptLink">@Html.DisplayFor(m => d.DeptName)</p>

    <div class="SectListDiv" style="display:none;">

        @foreach (var s in d.SectionList)
        {
            <p id="@s.SectId" class="ListSectLink">@Html.DisplayFor(m => s.SectName)</p>

            <div class="UserListDiv" style="display:none;">
            CacheUsers(@s.UserList)

                @foreach (var u in s.UserList)
                {
                    <p Sect="@s.SectId" UserId="@u.Login" UserNum="@u.User_Num" class="ListUserLink">@Html.DisplayFor(m => u.Name) (@u.User_Num)</p>
                }

            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

This is all fine.

I now want to implement a search box which will search for the users.

In my mind there are 3 ways to do this.

1)Do an AJAX call to the DB to get the requested users. This will mean more requests to the server.

2)Use jQuery to search the Dom. I know how to do this but I think this will be slow.

3) Store the user list into a global object which is then accessed on search. As I understand it this is the best way to do it.

My issue is, I am struggling to store the user list (As just a list of users, without sections and departments) into a global variable.

I have tried to create a ViewBag variable which stores the data like this:

```
var CompleteUserList = new List<UserModel>();
foreach (var user in userList)
                    {
CompleteUserList.Add(new UserModel()
                        {
                            Name = user.Name,
                            Login = user.Login,
                            User_Num = user.User_Num
                        });
                    }
ViewBag.UserList = CompleteUserList;
```

And then storing it in a javascript variable:

```
var GlobalUsers =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.UserList));
```

This brings an error on Json ...

```
CS0103: The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context
```

Googling the error shows me I need to look at the properties of System.web.Helper but that didn't fix it.

Another idea I had was to call a client side function in the foreach loop on the page (above) which manually adds each record to a global variable but i'm not sure how to do that.

Is anyone able to help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you convert your CompleteUserList to JSON in your controller and assign it to the ViewBag?

Comment: So use ViewBag.UserList = Json(CompleteUserList); in the controller?

Then get iut with var GlobalUsers = JSON.parse("@ViewBag.UserList");?

I can't get that to work. It isn't returning the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I decided to do it:

Controller:

```
ViewBag.UserList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CompleteUserList, Formatting.None)
```

Script:

```
    var GlobalUsers = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(ViewBag.UserList));
alert(GlobalUsers[0].Name);
```